# Is Heroku with Cloud SQL a good match?

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-sql

is anyone using Heroku with Cloud SQL (either Postgres or MySQL)? How's the latency?

Cloud SQL and Heroku live in different datacenters. Is network speed an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and had terrible results.  Latency was too high for my purposes (100ms) and I was unable to get it to a reasonable level.  Heroku is on AWS `us-east-1` metal (North Virginia), and I was using a Google cloud sql instance in `us-central-1b` (Iowa), so in my case this definitely contributed to the problem.  As a test, I made a replica of my DB in Google's `us-east4` region, which is closer to  AWS `us-east-1`, and it seemed to be an improvement, but was still >50ms for me.